# Chain Rule of Logarithm?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, soft-question, logarithms

The students are taught the well known  change base rule of logarithm:

\begin{align}\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}\end{align} Most text books proves it by invoking  $(a^x)^y=a^{xy}$ to show:
\begin{align}\log_c a\times\log_a b=\log_c b\end{align}

**Question:**

Why don't we call it  Chain Rule of Logarithm (at least as a second name)?
Is it because the way we use it is almost alway in the change of base format or something else?
\begin{align}
\log_a b\times\log_b c\times\log_c d\times\log_d e\times\cdots\times\log_y z=\log_a z\end{align}

It is easy to remember and the students  can have fun to continue chaining  it (similar to the change rule of derivative).

Comment: Seems your product should have $\log_c d$ as third factor [your product skips that].

Comment: @coffeemath A chain with a missing link is a broken chain, thanks :-).

Comment: A few moments of googling (delete "derivative", delete "calculus" to avoid many false-positive hits) led to [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2278298/13130) and the usage in [these books](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Chain+Rule+%5D+In+general%2C+log%22&tbm=bks), so clearly others have anticipated you. My guess for why this phase (or a similar one) hasn't been adopted is that no one needs to apply the base change over and over again in a single base change situation -- just change from the base you have to the base you want, without going through many intermediary bases.

Comment: @Joe At some places, people call 12:30AM  0:30AM  or 12:30 PM 0:30PM. Not sure what the reason is.

Comment: Why not call the usual “chain rule” a “catenary rule”, instead? Because people don’t. As to proving it, the way I do it is by noting that if $\log_a(b) = r$, then $a^r=b$, so $b=c^{\log_c(a^r)} = c^{r\log_a(c)}$, so $\log_c(b) = r\log_c(a) = \log_a(b)\log_c(a)$.

Comment: Your displayed equation does not match the formula you say you are trying to prove. The second displayed equation leads to $\log_b(c) = \log_a(c)/\og_a(b)$.

Comment: @arturo thanks! My intention was to have a,b,c flow there to illustrate the chain characteristic. If it is confusing, I will change it.

Comment: I think your first two displays should be compatible. Right now, you claim that you will use method B to prove formula A, but you aren’t proving formula A, you are proving a version of formula A with variables permuted without saying so. It’s like saying “I’m going to prove that $y=x^2$“, and then having a formula that leads to $x=y^2$.

Comment: @aarturo It does not try to prove, but  show that when people prove it, it usually come out in product form(as you illustrated), rather than quotient form. The feature of chain is right here during the proof process.

Comment: It wasn’t about that; it was about the confusion generated when you have two expressions that are clearly meant to be connected, but they are not because in one of them you’ve permuted the variables. But you’ve fixed that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A side note:

The argument of the current factor must be equal to the base of following factor. I´ve colored the corresponding parameters.

$$\begin{align}\log_{\color{blue}{a}} \color{red}{b}\times\log_{\color{red}{b}} \color{orange}{c}\times\log_{\color{orange}{c}} \color{green}{d}\times\cdots\times\log_y \color{yellowgreen}{z}=\log_{\color{blue}{a}} \color{yellowgreen}z\end{align}$$

I hope you see the difference to your term. The chain rule is about derivatives and the concept is very different from the rule you´ve posted.

It is more related to the overall growth rate $r$, if you have n consecutive growth rates ($r_i$), with $r_i=\frac{y_{i+1}}{y_i}-1$.

$$1+r=\frac{y_{1}}{y_0}\cdot \frac{y_{2}}{y_1}\cdot \ldots \cdot \frac{y_{n-1}}{y_{n-2}} \cdot \frac{y_{n}}{y_{n-1}}=\frac{y_{n}}{y_{0}}$$

The rule you´ve posted is related to the concept of the  geometric mean.

Answer (score 0):

Well, finally I found another user or person who concurs with my idea. I discovered this relation personally.

\begin{align}
\log_a b\times\log_b c\times\log_c d\times\log_d e\times\cdots\times\log_y z=\log_a z\end{align}

but this is just a special case of

\begin{align}
\log_{b_1}{a_1} \times \log_{b_2}{a_2} \times \log_{b_3}{a_3} \times \log_{b_4}{a_4} \times \cdots \times \log_{b_n}{a_n} = \log_{b_1}{a_{\pi_1}} \times \log_{b_2}{a_{\pi_2}} \times \log_{b_3}{a_{\pi_3}} \times \log_{b_4}{a_4} \times \cdots \times \log_{b_n}{a_{\pi_n}} \end{align}

where [${\pi}$ is any permutation of the subscripts 1, ..., n.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_logarithmic_identities#Changing_the_base)

Answer (score 0):

Well, I think this "chain form" of base changing is as it [another form of another identity in reversing ts proof](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/854588/name-for-a-logarithm-identity-property?rq=1)

$\large n^{\log_bx} = x^{\log_bn}$

One revering its simple proof is:

> $\large c^{\log_ab} = b^{\log_ac}$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \log_bc^{log_ab}=log_bb^{log_ac}$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \log_ab\cdot \log_bc=\log_bb\cdot \log_ac$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \log_ab\cdot \log_bc=1\cdot \log_ac$

\begin{align}\log_a b\times\log_b c=\log_a c\end{align}

One simple proof is:

> $\log_ab\cdot \log_bc=1\cdot \log_ac$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \log_ab\cdot \log_bc=\log_bb\cdot \log_ac$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \log_bc^{log_ab}=log_bb^{log_ac}$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large c^{\log_ab} = b^{\log_ac}$

Then how do we proceed our proof from two terms to many terms? Use \begin{align}\log_a b = \frac{\log_c b}{\log_c a}\end{align}

> $\log_a b\times\log_b c\times\log_c d\times\log_d e\times\cdots\times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large  \frac{1}{\log_b a} \times \log_b c \times \frac{1}{log_dc} \times \log_d e \times \cdots\times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large  \frac{ \log_b c}{\log_b a} \times \frac{\log_d e}{log_dc} \times \frac{\log_f g}{log_fe}\times \cdots\times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \log_a c \times log_ce \times \log_eg \times \log_gi \times \log_ik \times \log_km \times \log_mo \times \log_oq \times \log_qs \times \log_su \times \log_uw \times \log_wy \times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \cdots$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \log_ae \times \log_ei \times \log_im \times \log_mq \times \log_qu \times \log_uy \times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \cdots$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \log_ai \times \log_iq \times \log_qy \times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \cdots$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \log_aq \times \log_qy \times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \cdots$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \log_ay \times\log_y z=\log_a z$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \cdots$
>
> $\large \Rightarrow \large \log_a z=\log_a z$